# How can a C# programmer build software for iPhone?

Tags: c#, iphone

What should I learn to develop software for iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: Software is a countable noun?

Comment: Edited - for search more than anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Beginning Objective C for the C# guy](http://scottcreynolds.com/archive/2009/02/05/beginning-objective-c-for-the-c-guy.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Learn Objective C.

Comment: There's more and more people downvoting just to be obstinate, simply because an answer, although 100% correct, is not what they want to hear. I'm sure they wanted to hear about Mono, compiling back through 4 or 5 alpha quality open source projects and installable only on a jailbroken phone. When in reality, assuming the posters goal is to sell an app on the App Store, your answer is the first, best step toward that goal.

Comment: Thanks @mmc. That's what I thought. Right tool for the right job.

Comment: Yeah, 3 of the top 25 books in the Computers and Internet category on Amazon.com were about Objective C last time I looked.

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking about developing games, take a look at [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps look into [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)?  There is an article dealing with this question [here](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/01/open-source-mono-framework-brings-c-to-iphone-and-wii.ars).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the IPhone SDK, you can use Mono (Open Source .Net implementation). Check http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Iphone

Answer (score 0):

iPhone Applications are using Apple's tools like Xcode, objective c, etc.  A C# developer would be learning a new language, new libraries, and using a simulator to run the application.  Details are at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/